# How to run a program in kernel mode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am currently learning linux and want to run a program in kernel mode in order to compute the difference between the time taken by program in user and kernel mode.

Answer (score 0):

you can hook the system call and add onc that will be your program your program run it in kernel mode to add "systme call" you need to add line to the file /boot/system.map-kernel version to find your kernel version /proc/version LKM tool can help you do that